# queryContext - filtering with numbers neo4j/lucene

Tags: filter, lucene, neo4j

I'm trying to filter a wildcard query in neo/lucene using numeric range.
I want to search for all nodes (documents) having key "actor" starting with "rob" and age > 20:

```
WildcardQuery luceneQuery  = new WildcardQuery( new Term("actor", "rob*" ));
QueryContext qx = new QueryContext(luceneQuery)
            .numericRange("age", 20, null)
                .sortNumeric("age", true);      
IndexHits<Node> hits = lucene.query(qx);
```

Once I add numeric range the wildCard query does not works, it only orders by numeric range.
Is it possible to combine both wildcard and numeric?

Thanks,
Daniele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want to use a BooleanQuery to combine the WildcardQuery with the numeric range query. (I normally use QueryParser, myself, rather than building the queries by hand.)

For your example query, the QueryParser syntax would look like:

```
+actor:rob* +age:{20 TO 123}
```

where *+age:{20 TO 123}* asks for age > 20 AND age < 123 (the oldest well-documented person lived to 122). The "+" operators force both of those terms to occur in the document.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution!!!
I'm curious how would you use QueryParser for example to accomplish this task? It may save me a lot of time the next time!