# Neo4j: Compound queries with numeric range

Tags: neo4j, lucene

I have a relationship index named dates, which indexes on 2 fields - "year-numeric" and "type". I intend to use range queries on year-numeric and so have indexed it as numeric

```
 dates.add(role1, "year-numeric", new ValueContext(2000).indexNumeric());
```

where role1 is a relationship between 2 nodes.

In my graph, I have 2 types of relationship which is captured by the 2nd field "type".

While I am able to query it individually:

```
IndexHits<Relationship> hits = dates.query(QueryContext.numericRange("year-numeric", 1990, 2004),null,null);
```

and

```
hits = dates.query("type:occurs");
```

I would be obliged, if someone can help me in combining together these two conditions.

I have checked here: [queryContext - filtering with numbers neo4j/lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155578/querycontext-filtering-with-numbers-neo4j-lucene) but I am unable to understand the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: how about `dates.query("year-numeric:[1990 to 2004] and type:occurs")` ? (have not tried myself - just a shoot from the hip). Don't forget to add the type to the index as well `dates.add(role1, "type", role1.getType().name())`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It does not work: I am getting the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'year-numeric:[1990 to 2004] and type:occurs': Encountered " <RANGEIN_GOOP> "2004 "" at line 1, column 22.
Was expecting:
    "]"

Comment: You probably have to use a query object instance that is a BooleanQuery or an AndQuery or something like that.

Comment: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-lucene-extras.html#indexing-lucene-query-objects

Comment: Thanks! The booleanQuery was a good hint.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the inputs in comments, I did some more digging in lucene and came up with the following solution. Not sure whether it is the most optimal one though:

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
TermQuery query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("type","occurs"));
NumericRangeQuery<Integer> pageQueryRange = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("year-numeric", 1990, 2005, true, true);
booleanQuery.add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
booleanQuery.add(pageQueryRange, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);   
IndexHits<Relationship> hits = dates.query(booleanQuery);
```